# Vuetify bottom navigation not working on smaller screen

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, bottomnavigationview

I am using Vuetify's [bottom navigation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/bottom-navigation/#bottom-navigation) component in my web-app. I have multiple section for which I need navigation items on my bottom navigation bar. I am using the following component,

```js
<template>
    <v-bottom-navigation
            :value="activeBtn"
            color="primary"
            horizontal
    >
        <v-btn>
            <span>Home</span>
            <v-icon class="material-icons">home</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn>
            <span>About</span>
            <v-icon class="material-icons">person_pin</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn>
            <span>Learn</span>
            <v-icon class="material-icons">school</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn>
            <span>Device</span>
            <v-icon class="material-icons">computer</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn>
            <span>Ideas</span>
            <v-icon class="material-icons">emoji_objects</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn>
            <span>Settings</span>
            <v-icon class="material-icons">settings</v-icon>
        </v-btn>


    </v-bottom-navigation>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "BottomNav",
        data() {
            return {
                activeBtn: 0,
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

This component is used in my following app.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app id="app">
        <Header/>
        <v-content>
            <router-view/>
        </v-content>
        <BottomNav/>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

This leads to proper bottom menu on laptop/desktop as follows

[image]

However, when I reduce the screen size or check it on my mobile, it will screw up the layout like following

[image]

Anyone has any idea about how to handle this? I was expecting behavior like Android bottom navigation i.e. hiding labels and horizontal scrolling. But current Vuetify documentation has no such function mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually add `overflow-x: scroll;` css property to the bottom navigation component.

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside the component `<style>` tag with the bottom navigation:

```
.v-bottom-navigation {
  justify-content: start;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

The `v-bottom-navigation` component already uses this class, so no need to manually add to it.